# Как перенести изменения из одной ветки в другую?

Tags: git

Условно у меня есть две ветки {`develop-release-13.x`, `cmake`}

Я перешел в ветку `cmake`, внес изменения в файл CMakeLists.txt и должен был сменить ветку на `develop-release-13.x` и продолжить работу, но забыл это сделать и внес изменения в несколько файлов в ветке `cmake`.

Я еще не делал `git commit` с этими изменениями.

Теперь мне нужно все изменения из ветки `cmake` перенести в ветку `develop-release-13.x`, не делая коммитов с этими изменениями в ветку `cmake`.

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Делайте коммит в неправильную ветку, потом rebase этого коммита в правильную.

Comment: я бы сделал так: `git stash && git checkout develop-release-13.x && git stash pop`

Comment: `rebase` перенесёт **всю** `cmake` ветку. этого не надо. @user7860670 сначала создаётся **новая** ветка `son` поверх `cmake` и эту `son` переносить можно на `develop`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Вообще-то rebase позволяет и один коммит перенести, новые ветки плодить нет необходимости.

Comment: может быть, эту опцию не помню, @user7860670 проблема в том, что нужно индивидуально к каждым файлам подойти, один файл сюда, другие туда. наверное вопрос в том, как каждый файл делать rebase индивидуально.

Comment: @AlexGlebe *"наверное вопрос в том, как каждый файл"* - в вопросе же прямо написано *"все изменения из ветки cmake перенести"*

Comment: почитайте вопрос @user7860670 *"внес изменения в файл CMakeLists.txt"* (`cmake`). Скорее всего нужно чётче задать вопрос, что куда.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Я так понял, что изменения в этот файл были уже закомичены, а потом ОП случайно продолжил работу на той же ветке, забыв переключится. Но на самом деле это не принципиально, можно же внести в переносимый коммит изменения кроме файла CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: а может быть проще `git commit CMakeLists.txt` ; `git checkout develop-release-13.x` ? @user7860670

Comment: @AlexGlebe git может пожаловаться, что checkout приведет к потере изменений и не выполнит

Comment: не, а , всё будет пучком. @user7860670

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не хочется делать изменений, можно применить старый способ, который точно работал.

## способ простой, древний

Вначале делаем git diff и сохраняем все в файл

```
git diff > mychange.diff
```

сам файл сохраняем в надежное место, ну мало чего.

Теперь можно удалить локальные изменения

```
git checkout .
```

перейти на нужную ветку

```
git checkout develop-release-13.x
```

и там "накатить изменения".

```
git apply mychange.diff
```

При всей странности этого способа (а он странен, согласен), у него есть куча преимуществ.

- дифом (патчем) можно поделиться с другом
- диф можно себе сохранить и потом применять по мере надобности (например, у меня был диф, который включал специфичные отладочные настройки)
- диф можно послать по почте:) а с той стороны его могут применить через git am
- диф можно применить и через команду patch, которая бывает даже там, где нет git
- диф можно отправить на проверку по почте (такая себе система ревью)

По факту, git stash делает ровно то же самое. `git stash` сохраняет диф локально и откатывает изменения, `git stash pop` примняет этот диф. Эта команда может работать не очень хорошо, если в репозитории ещё нет коммитов (хотя, по правде, много комманд гита работают странно, если в репозитории нет коммитов).

## stash, рекомендованный способ

После выполнения `git stash` хорошо бы посмотреть на репозиторий `git status` - в ветке не должно быть изменений после этого. Если изменения остались - что то пошло не так. Также хорошо посмотреть в `git stash list` на то, какие там есть дифы (изменения). А также, через `git stash show -p` посмотреть на диф этого изменения. делать `git add .` перед тем, как записать изменения в stash, не нужно (это я просто помню с удаленного вопроса).

## cherry-pick, перетаскиватель коммитов

Ок, что ещё есть (предполагаем, что коммитить в ветки просто так не хотим).

Можно создать временную ветку

```
git checkout -b temp
```

закоммитить в нее

```
git add . # или что там нужно
git commit -m "my changes"
```

и запомним хеш коммита. Идем в нужную ветку

```
git chechout main
```

и добавляем туда коммит

```
git cherry-pick <запомненный hash>
```

Возможно, будут конфликты, тогда их нужно решить и доделать коммит вручную. Если конфликтов нет, то оно применится сразу и закоммитит.

Теперь, проверив, что все ок, можно смело удалить ту временную ветку

```
git branch -D test
```

буква D большая, так как ветку никуда не мержили. Все.

Comment: о, и сюда привели минусатора

Comment: Крайне длинный и путанный ответ с массой лишних манипуляция. ¿У вас что, какая-то личная неприязнь к rebase?

Comment: можно и ребейз взять, но оно тут не нужно. stash самое оно. Если ответ не понятен, это ещё не значит, что он неверный

Answer (score 1):

Делайте `commit` с изменениями в неправильную ветку cmake, а затем `rebase`:

```
git rebase --onto develop-release-13.x cmake~1 cmake
```

После этого состояние истории будет как будто вы сделали изменения и коммит в ветку `develop-release-13.x`, а ветку `cmake` даже не трогали.

Comment: иногда бывает, что в ветку действительно нельзя просто так коммитить...

Comment: @KoVadim Если подобная экстравагантная ситуация имеет место, то она тривиально обходится созданием ветки, в которую коммитить можно. Причем возможно это будет полезным в любом случае, если планируемые изменения для правильной ветки являются началом работы над какой-то новой задачей или т.п.

Comment: собственно этот вариант я тоже у себя описал.